# aura:if visibility issue with force:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura-if, rendering

I am having a problem with **aura:if** tag. As when my condition is false, my field will be invisible. The Problem is when my condition again went true from false then only Label of my inputfield is visible, the textbox got disappear.

**onload when condition is true by default**

[image: onload when condition is true by default]

**when condition is false from true**

[image: when condition is false from true]

**when condition is true from false again**

[image: when condition is true from false again]

here is my code

Component Code:

```
<aura:attribute name="ShowSection" type="boolean" default="true" />

<lightning:button label="Test" onclick="{!c.SelectAction}"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.ShowSection == true}"> 
    <tr><td>
        <label>
            Assigned To
        </label>
        <force:inputField aura:id="owId" value="{!v.Task.OwnerId}"/>                    
    </td></tr>
</aura:if>
```

JS Code:

```
SelectAction: function(component, event, helper) {
    
    var dataToShow = component.get("v.SelectedData");
    if(dataToShow == 'My Data')
    {
        component.set("v.ShowSection", false);    
    }
    else
    {
        component.set("v.ShowSection", true);
    }
}
```

please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue as explained here  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCebQAE

the workaround mentioned  is to use <aura:renderIf >

like this

```
<aura:renderIf  isTrue="{!v.ShowSection == true}"> 
    <tr><td>
        <label>
            Assigned To
        </label>
        <force:inputField aura:id="owId" value="{!v.Task.OwnerId}"/>                    
    </td></tr>
</aura:renderIf>
```

Comment: perfect, problem solved! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the fields on UI, you can also play with `slds-show` and `slds-hide` classes to toggle the field visibility.

Something like this:

```
<div class="{!v.ShowSection ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide'}">
```